# How to write a generic templated wrapper for type specific acess functions?

Tags: c++, pugixml

I'm trying to write a generic wrapper for the C++ pugi xml library that can save and store values to/from xml.

They have implemented their xml node attributes' (stored as strings) access functions into functions such as `attribute.as_int()`, `attribute.as_bool()` etc.

I want to achieve the same functionality seen in the nlohmann::json library where you can call `.get<T>()` on some json object and get some type.

The only way I can think of (which may not even work) is to use template specialization:

```
template <>
int foo<int>(xml_attribute param)
{
    return param.as_int();
}

template <>
bool foo<bool>(xml_attribute param)
{
    return param.as_bool();
}
```

And so forth.

Which seems to result in almost as much code as writing a non-generic wrapper...

Comment: The wrapper should have more code, but after, you can use foo in a generic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an extra parameter to create different overloads based on type, and then use overload resolution to find the right function. `TypeTag` is an empty class we can use to distinguish between different overloads:

```
template<class T>
struct TypeTag{ /* empty */ };
```

Once we have that, we can write `read_as` functions based on the tag:

```
int read_as(xml_attribute param, TypeTag<int>) {
    return param.as_int(); 
}
bool read_as(xml_attribute param, TypeTag<bool>) {
    return param.as_bool(); 
}
float read_as(xml_attribute param, TypeTag<float>) {
    return param.as_float(); 
}
double read_as(xml_attribute param, TypeTag<double>) {
    return param.as_double();
}
const pugi::char_t* read_as(xml_attribute param, TypeTag<const pugi::char_t*) {
    return param.as_string(); 
}
```

Making a generic template is now pretty simple:

```
template<class T>
T read_as(xml_attribute param) {
    return read_as(param, TypeTag<T>()); 
}
```

This solution works in C++11, and it will compile faster than a series of `if constexpr` checks because the compiler can look up the correct version through overload resolution, rather than having to do a series of checks.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to do but didn't understand exactly how.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your approach is actually not that bad. I'll probably stick with it.

There is another way, however.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto foo(xml_attribute param)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
          return param.as_int();
    }
    else if constexpr (/*..*/){//...} //and so on
}
```